# How to disable the onCreate() invoke after onMultiWindowModeChanged

Tags: android, multiscreen

I'm trying to do some different customized config in/out MultiWindowMode for my activity.   I guess the right way is doing that in `onMultiWindowModeChanged()` function.  But the problem is that every time `onCreate()` and `onStart()` will be invoked after `onMultiWindowModeChanged()`, then all the modification in `onMultiWindowModeChanged()` is covered by `onCreate()` and `onStart()`.

For now, I used `isInMultiWindowMode()` in `onCreate` to implement my logic.  My question is how could I disable the `onCreate()` invoke when enter/exit multi window mode?   Then I can implement logic in `onMultiWindowModeChanged()` as google suggested.

(For orientation change, we can set `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` to disable the `onCreate()` invoke.  Is there any similar solution for multi window mode change?)

Comment: Excellent query.Im also searching for the answers of this query.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little bit late, but for people who are still searching for the answer this is what I found in [the Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element#config):

> **Note**: To handle all [Multi-Window](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window) related configuration changes use both "`screenLayout`" and "`smallestScreenSize`". Multi-Window is supported in Android 7.0 (API level 24) or higher.